# Forever stop node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, forever

I started my server with

```
forever start start.js
```

And it runs normally, when I tried to stop it with

```
forever stopall
```

It removes from `forever list` as it should

But when I run `lsof -i tcp:3000` my server still appears

I tried to use `kill -9 PROCESS_PID` but the process comes back with a different pid, and my server still running

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the only process running.
You can use, `forever stop 0`

Comment: I already stop it with stopall command... The PID stills up to

Comment: @PedroSturmer, try it once, Alternatively do you know the name of the process?

Comment: when i run forever stop 0 it says "error:   Forever cannot find process with id: 0", there's no process running on forever, forever list it's empty

Comment: @PedroSturmer, did you try to kill it with the name too?

Comment: I found out that wasent forever that was restarting my app, it was another upstream called pm2, thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[fkill-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fkill-cli)**

Install it globally using `npm i -g fkill-cli` & then run `fkill` in terminal

[image]

Comment: when I type "node" or "forever" it says "No results..."

Comment: it should be `node` & not `forever`. also, check out other examples in the GitHub repo like supplying port or pid. also, try using `nodemon` instead of `forever` in future. it works well for me.